# Не могу вспомнить слово

Tags: выбор-слов

Как называется слово, когда каждый год и в определенное число делаешь что-то?
Не могу слово вспомнить. Это как в фильме "Ирония судьбы, или С лёгким паром!", когда они в баню ходили.

Comment: Понятно: 1 января!  Лукашин тоже мало что мог вспомнить.

Comment: У нас с друзьями есть такое слово... Оно называется слово.

Answer (score 2):

Из фильма «Ирония судьбы, или С легким паром!»:

> Понимаете, каждый год 31 декабря мы с друзьями ходим в баню. Это у нас такая **традиция**...

Answer (score 1):

*Группа "Би-2", перефразировав известную фразу из культовой "Иронии судьбы", может со всей уверенностью заявить: "Понимаете, каждый год мы с друзьями играем концерт с симфоническим оркестром. **Это у нас такая традиция**".*

В некоторых случаях слово "традиция" можно заменить подходящими [синонимами](http://jeck.ru/tools/SynonymsDictionary/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F):
обычай, обыкновение, (так) принято, (так) повелось.

*Он всегда имел **обыкновение** упрятать на ночь полпудовую краюху хлеба и фунта четыре сала и чувствовал на этот раз в желудке своем какое-то несносное одиночество.*
Н. Гоголь. Вий

У В. И. Даля есть пословица: *У нас такая **поведенция*** (обычай).